# Trouble with Negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

On my exam, I was told to write the negation for "for some x in R, such that for every y in R, xy > y". I wrote "For all y in R, xy < R" and it was incorrect. What is the proper negation for this and similar questions?

Comment: Ah woops, that should be <y, not < R!

Answer (score 0):

The negation of:

- $a > b$ is $a\le b$
- $a < b$ is $a\ge b$
- $a \ge b$ is $a < b$
- $a \le b$ is $a > b$

To explain why does it work like this:

$a\ge b$ is the same as:

> $a$ is ("greater than" **or** "equal to") b

Negating it:

> $a$ is **not** ("greater than" **or** "equal to") b
>
> $a$ is (**not** "greater than") **and** (**not** "equal to") b
>
> $a$ is "less than" b

And the same way for all the others.